# Toolbar + Navigation Bar + Segmented Control?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I'm trying to find a way to layout an application that includes a tab bar on the bottom, a navigation bar on the top, and a row of buttons on the navigation bar that switches views (on the first tab).

I've drawn a very rough sketch (sorry!), but I hope it illustrates the intent.

[image: App layout]
On the bottom, there are two tabs (tab1, and tab2).

When Tab1 is selected, the navigation bar will have 3 buttons that will show different views (tab1_1, tab1_2, tab1_3).

When Tab2 is selected, the navigation bar won't show any buttons, but rather some simple text.

At this point, I have the following scheme in my application delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[Tab1_ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Tab1_ViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[Tab2_ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Tab2_ViewController" bundle:nil];

    tab1NavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    tab2NavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tab1NavController, tab2NavController, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I was wondering if I need to redo how I'm doing things in order to achieve the layout as in the picture.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to do it using IB?

Comment: Agreed, IB would probably be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this for my current project...i hope this will help you....

At first take `UITabbarController` at your first viewController [first sketch you have given]

For your first view use this code....

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

dashBoardView = [[DashboardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DashboardViewController" bundle:nil];
dashBoardView.title = @"dashBoardView";
UINavigationController *mydashboarController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dashBoardView] autorelease];
mydashboarController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[listOfViewControllers addObject:mydashboarController];
[dashBoardView release];

ordersView = [[OrdersViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OrdersViewController" bundle:nil];
    ordersView.title = @"ordersView";
UINavigationController *myorderController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ordersView] autorelease];
myorderController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[listOfViewControllers addObject:myorderController];
[ordersView release];

orderList = [[OrderListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OrderListViewController" bundle:nil];
orderList.title = @"orderList";
UINavigationController *myorderListController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:orderList] autorelease];
myorderListController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[listOfViewControllers addObject:myorderListController];
[orderList release];

productView = [[ProductViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductViewController" bundle:nil];
    productView.title = @"productView";
UINavigationController *myproductController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:productView] autorelease];
[listOfViewControllers addObject:myproductController];
[productView release];

[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:listOfViewControllers animated:YES];

NSArray *segmentTextContent = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"Dashboard", @""),NSLocalizedString(@"Order", @""),
                               NSLocalizedString(@"Product", @""),NSLocalizedString(@"More", @""),
                               nil];
UISegmentedControl* segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentTextContent];
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
segmentedControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 40);
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

//defaultTintColor = [segmentedControl.tintColor retain];   // keep track of this for later

segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:8.0 saturation:8.0 brightness:8.0 alpha:1.0];
segmentedControl.alpha = 0.8;

self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;
[segmentedControl release]; 
}
```

If it is not clear to you then please knock...